# Power Apps custom form question on formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp

I've designed a custom input form for a Sharepoint list in Power Apps, and I had two questions on formatting:

1. My formatting in preview mode looks fine, however once published in the Sharepoint list itself the field heights, text positioning, etc. is changed.  Any idea how I can ensure that the formatting of the form remains consistent from Power Apps to Sharepoint?  For reference, the formatting is shown below.
2. Upon opening the form in Sharepoint, certain fields (see Issue Type, Priority, Status in the images below) in the form are highlighted/selected without any action on my end - any thoughts on how to remove this?

Custom form in Power Apps previewer:

[image]

Custom form in Sharepoint:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have observed, there is indeed a difference between the Form format in Power Apps preview mode and the actual Sharepoint Form format. At present, there is no way  to make the Form format of Power Apps and Sharepoint completely consistent.

**Cancel Highlight style**

Please modify the value of **HoverFill**

- **HoverFill : RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: Hi, user96941.Thanks for your reply. I am honored to be able to help you. Have a nice day!